# How to recommend future elective courses based on past course grades

Tags: r, correlation, decision-tree, recommendation-engine

I have grades(or marks) of 150 students for 16 courses.

I would like to use Decision trees as my first model for recommending courses in which students would perform well in future elective courses. There are 17 elective courses to choose from.

The data for future courses consist of high missing values from 60% to 85% because each student can select only 5 optional courses out of 17 available courses. But there is no missing data present in past year 16 courses.

I think one way to recommend is to use correlation between past courses and future elective courses. So, If a student did very well in a course which is Mathematics focused, the system or model would recommend an elective course which is more mathematically oriented. but the problem is data is so sparse that its not working imputing.

All the courses are related to Computer Science stream. I thought of grouping courses in categories such as: mathematics focused, or programming focused or Networking or Business etc..

but **I don't understand how to approach this problem using decision trees. How to create a target or class field. The process I guess requires 2 steps One to find correlation between courses and someway to save them. Second to use it to compare with past course**

I have 3 fields(courses in first column, Marks in 2nd col and Grades in 3rd col).

Courses refer to names of the courses(nominal field)

Marks refer to 1 to 100(numerical field)

Grades refer to A to F(ordinal field)

Marks and Grades are highly correlated as Grades are mainly calculated from Marks. for ex: Marks (above 70) leads to A grade, Marks between 60-69 leads to B grade. Which is a plus point as I can create a Decision Tree out of Marks and Grades both and see which recommends well.

All the courses do correlate with past courses by some percent of similarity. But I dont know calculate the correlation when data is so sparse that imputing may lose the essence of original data.

**Any Idea or Thought on how to tackle this problem is appreciated!.**

I am aware of decision trees and their variations. But the problem I am facing is on how to approach the problem step by step. I think don't have a target field to apply decision trees on.

I will be making other 2 models as well Artificial Neural Network and Support Vector Machines and finally compare which model does the best.

```
In below dataset, 
F27.. means Yr1 course, 
F28.. means Yr2 
F29.. means Yr3 and 
F20.. means Yr4
```

**Dataset Format - 1**

```
Student_id,F27SA,F27PX,F27IS,F27SB,F27CS,F28IN,F28DA,F28PL,F28SD,F28DM,F29AI,F29FA,F29SO,F29PD,F29OC,F29FB,F20DL,F20BC,F20GP,F20MA,F20MC,F20RO,F20RS,F20DP,F20DV
    55,48,39,56,52,56,52,72,69,83,63,37,79,67,67,66,88,NA,NA,58,NA,73,NA,87,NA,NA
    68,87,74,70,88,57,47,58,64,49,67,59,62,65,65,83,62,NA,NA,62,85,NA,NA,NA,47,NA
    70,82,77,79,97,56,41,62,76,41,61,53,75,66,66,79,76,NA,NA,62,84,NA,NA,NA,40,NA
    99,88,79,75,81,45,68,47,57,68,52,66,61,64,64,58,51,60,75,84,NA,NA,71,80,NA,NA
    100,80,91,69,70,35,68,58,50,55,48,49,66,45,45,59,78,62,63,NA,NA,NA,NA,80,NA,NA
    101,95,76,70,98,74,56,70,73,55,85,62,61,73,73,73,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,68,NA
    103,83,77,58,60,67,50,54,60,44,45,43,37,53,53,53,50,NA,41,37,62,22,48,NA,NA,NA
    105,87,68,78,96,67,57,85,77,76,88,75,67,50,50,74,79,62,59,82,91,56,NA,NA,NA,NA
    106,82,82,71,77,52,65,66,45,45,56,73,75,75,75,41,66,66,69,59,NA,NA,69,71,NA,NA
    107,84,75,77,93,64,61,77,53,47,63,60,54,64,64,82,70,59,75,NA,NA,59,NA,NA,60,NA
    108,80,61,52,57,67,60,40,59,58,75,17,19,40,40,21,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

**Dataset Format - 2**

```
Student_id,Course_code,Grades
55,F27SA,48
68,F27SA,87
70,F27SA,82
99,F27SA,88
100,F27SA,80
101,F27SA,95
103,F27SA,83
105,F27SA,87
106,F27SA,82
107,F27SA,84
108,F27SA,80
109,F27SA,85
```

Full dataset can be found at : https://github.com/MURL1DHAR/Dissertation_Project/tree/master/extras **yr123.csv and yr1234.csv**

Comment: Hello: Cool idea!!, I think your data should be structured in a slightly different way, first I think one of your columns should be each student, and then one for each of the past courses where I would put the marks. and Finally I would build a regression based model (GBM, Random Forests) to predict the mark they would get in each of the elective courses. With that you could build a dataframe of predicted results, and then get the top x subjects were a student would get their best marks. I'd be happy to collaborate with this. it sounds fun

Comment: Yes. I can share the data with you in github.I have the data in exact way you told would work. I used spread function in R language to spread courses along the column. And the first column is student_id. I will update my questions with some sample data. Please if you could show some steps on how to predict the marks they would get in each elective courses for top x subjects?

Comment: @DerekCorcoran I have added sample dataset in the question and link to full dataset. year 1, 2 and 3 is for training and year 4 for prediction. there is some missing values. I used MICE to fill it in for yr 1,2 and 3. Please let me know if you work on it. Thanks your support is appreciated.

Comment: @MurkudharFichandia, just saw your replies, I will work on it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how to start, with loops and or apply you should be able to get your results, let me know if you need more help with it:

#### Read in your Data

```
Subjects <- read.csv("~/Downloads/yr1234.csv")

library(caret)
```

#### Train and predict for subject F20DL

```
df1<- Subjects[,1:18]
#Get only the complete cases
df1 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

You can actually impute data to df1 for NAs, but I don't think you want to do this with this data

Fit random forest model

```
Fit1 <- train(x = df1[,2:17], y = df1[,18], method = "rpart1SE", na.action = na.pass)
```

now you predict to the new students you want to predict their marks in F20DL

```
Subjects$pred_F20DL<- predict(Fit1, Subjects)
```

#### fit and predict for "F20BC"

```
df2<- Subjects[,c(1:17,19)]
df2 <- df2[complete.cases(df2),]

Fit2 <- train(x = df2[,2:17], y = df2[,18], method = "rpart1SE", na.action = na.pass)

Subjects$pred_F20BC<- predict(Fit2, Subjects)
```

#### Sort subjects by predicted value

This loop will sort each vector by predicted value. obviously, this is only for the 2 subjects modeled in the fitted models above, but if you have more predicted values you have to add the columns an not only have columns 27 and 28 in the loop

```
Recomendations <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(Subjects)){
  Recomendations[[i]] <- colnames(sort(Subjects[i,c(27:28)], decreasing = TRUE))
}

Recomendations <- do.call("rbind", Recomendations)

Recomendations <- cbind(Subjects$Student_id, Recomendations)

colnames(Recomendations) <- c("Student_id", "Recomendation1", "Recomendation2")

head(Recomendations)

     Student_id Recomendation1 Recomendation2
[1,] "55"       "pred_F20BC"   "pred_F20DL"  
[2,] "68"       "pred_F20DL"   "pred_F20BC"  
[3,] "70"       "pred_F20DL"   "pred_F20BC"  
[4,] "99"       "pred_F20DL"   "pred_F20BC"  
[5,] "100"      "pred_F20DL"   "pred_F20BC"  
[6,] "101"      "pred_F20DL"   "pred_F20BC"
```

I can also get a loop to do all the models automatically and then program apply to get the top X values, let me know if you need help for that too

Comment: @jenesaisquoi You are probably right, but with all his data it will be 9 columns, do you think apply or something else would be better?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I was looking how else to get the name of the max column for each row, and I am not sure how to do it, can you give me an alternative so I can edit my answer?

Comment: @DerekCorcoran I see what you did. we take all the courses in past and try to predict for future course but I dont get it why keep only complete cases? because that means we are not predicting marks for students with incomplete data for that particular course. that is, leaving out many students. Also, I ran the code you showed and I the model predicted the marks for complete cases only. which I think is not desired. you say its good if I impute those future courses? but how do I evaluate because lots of missing values, I dont have any way to know the error rate of imputation. Pls guide.

Comment: @DerekCorcoran Also, which.max finding out top 5 courses would not work because I think the solution above does not predict for every student as it considers only complete cases. So when listing out top 5 courses. it would be biased and true result would not be know as prediction was not done for all the future courses for all the students. I guess we will need to impute it and find a way to evaluate which imputation technique works well with least error.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia OK I am looking for this, for the first part of your problem you have to do `na.action = na.pass`, that will make it possible for the predictions to predict for every student, the last function I will work on it. I am editing the question changing the code, for now it will be able to predict the Marks for every student, I will work on the top 5 thing

Comment: @DerekCorcoran once again Thanks. Will mark answer as accepted once it works for top 5 courses.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Thanks, working on it, would it work if the result is a `data.frame` with the student's ID as the first column, and then the name of the potential subjects in descending predicted mark order?

Comment: @DerekCorcoran  Yes, any format would work. just that model should predict for all courses and all students. So analysis can be done on how accurate is recommendation. I dont expect you to work on accuracy. I can work on different algorithms and models to find high accuracy results b trial and error. I am just interested in how to approach part.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia sorry it's taking me a while, but I had to deliver something for my job. It will be done today though

Comment: @DerekCorcoran Take your time. its okay. I figured out few things. No need to impute future courses as it makes data unreal. I have to work on each course separately and with different train and test set depending on no. of complete cases. Also therefore no need for all students marks for all courses as the limitation is in dataset due to missing values. I will be limiting the no. of elective courses if I happen to. So that's sorted. I am going to try randomForest to findout weak and strong predictors, calvert function for feature selection, cross-validation., etc.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia added the function to sort the recommended values for student, tell me if something is missing.

Comment: Will test and let you know. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia, sorry to bother you, I was wondering if this is an actual real life project, I know a the headmistress of a school and I think I can get data from them, I thought this idea could be interesting for them. Shoot me an e-mail at derek.corcoran.barrios@gmail.com, I would like to talk about this